# singularity in boundary value problem

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve a non linear differential equation with variable parameter.

```
β[b_, c_] = (4 c - 14)/(12 b - 6 c - 9);
α[b_, c_] = (10 - 4 b)/(12 b - 6 c - 9);
eqn3[b_, c_, A_] = β[b, c] x f[x] - α[b, c] x^2 D[f[x], x] + 2 A^(b - 1) D[Sqrt[x] D[f[x]^b x^(2 + c), x], x];

b1 = 5/3;
c1 = -(1/2);

NDSolve[{eqn3[b1, c1, A] == 0, f[xmin] == 1, f[1] == p}, 
 f[x], {x, xmin, 1}, 
 Method -> {"Shooting", 
   "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[xmin] == 1, 
     Derivative[1][f][xmin] == -((2 + c1)/(b1 xmin))}}, 
 MaxSteps -> 1000]
```

with variable `xmin, A and p->0`. I am getting the error for `p<0.01`

> NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.4976549855466093`, step size is effectively
>   zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

Is there any way to sort the problem?.

Comment: Please format your code nicely in code blocks by using either back-ticks or indenting four spaces: for help, click the grey question mark on the right side of the editing toolbar.

Comment: Please give example values for `xmin`, `A`, and `p`. Setting them equal to zero causes problems.

Comment: Although better formatted, this questions is essentially identical to [102418](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102418/1063).  Please delete one or the other.

Answer (score 6):

The error occurs, because `f[x]` vanishes near `x == 0.4976549855466093`.  This problem can be overcome by experimenting to obtain a better estimate for `Derivative[1][f][xmin]`.  To illustrate, supply as the missing constants,

```
xmin = .01; p = 10^-3; A = 10;
```

Then,

```
s = NDSolve[{eqn3[b1, c1, A] == 0, f[xmin] == 1, f[1] == p}, f[x], {x, xmin, 1}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[xmin] == 1, 
    Derivative[1][f][xmin] == -94.81}}];
LogPlot[f[x] /. s, {x, xmin, 1}]
```

[image]

**Obtaining smaller `p`**

As noted at the beginning of this answer, the ODE becomes singular at `f[x] = 0`.  Hence, seeking a solution with `p = 0` or very near to zero causes the Shooting Method problems.  An automated approach for obtaining very small `p` is as follows.  First, obtain a numerical solution parameterized in terms of `Derivative[1][f][xmin] == bc`.

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqn3[b1, c1, A] == 0, f[xmin] == 1, 
    Derivative[1][f][xmin] == bc}, f, {x, xmin, 1}, {bc}]
```

and then `Plot` the value of `bc` at which `f[x] = 0` or the endpoint `x = 1` is reached, whichever occurs first.

```
Plot[(Quiet@s[bc]["Domain"])[[1, 2]], {bc, -100, -90}]
```

[image]

A precise value of the break in the slope of the curve is the desired value of `bc`, which can be obtain by

```
bl = -100; bu = -90; inf = 1;
Do[bt = (bl + bu)/2; If[Quiet@s[bt]["Domain"][[1, 2]] < inf, bl = bt, bu = bt], {i, 30}]
N[bu, 12]
(* -94.8105141707 *)
s[bu][1]
(* 4.96698*10^-8 *)
```

which is a reasonable approximation of zero.  For this approach to work, the initial estimates of `bl` and `bu` must bracket the desired value of `bc`.

Comment: This is good but can we have a solution for even smaller value of p, for example p<10^(-6) with the range 10^(-4)<xmin<10^(-1). I have always obtained a point of singularity in this which does not seem to be an intrinsic issue. Probably this is a boundary value problem as i can find a solution if p>=0.05.

Comment: @magesh  I have added a procedure that yields `p < 10^-7`.  It works equally well for `xmin = 10^-3`, but a much smaller value of `bc` is needed, `-921.268789973`.